# iOS - using a base name for files and appending the extension

Tags: ios, arrays, nsstring, filenames

I have lots of image file names stored in an array in my `RootViewController.m` that the user can select from.

```
myImages = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[myImages addObject:@"MR-MONO2-12-shoulder"];
[myImages addObject:@"brain_01"];
[myImages addObject:@"brain_02"];
[myImages addObject:@"brain_03"];
[myImages addObject:@"brain_04"]; ...
```

Once selected, a thumbnail image and the corresponding text file should be displayed in the detailView. I've named all the corresponding image files and text files similarly so, for example, `file1.jpg` corresponds to `file1.txt`. I want to make the base name of the file is a string on its own, to which I can append the appropriate extension when needed.

I'm pretty sure I'm overcomplicating this a lot, but with the numerous image and text files I  don't know how to write this so that the base name used is dependent upon the user's selection from the table. Is it possible to use the array I created to store all my images? The elements in the array are what I would make the base names for the files.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of options. If you just want to append a path extension, you can use `NSString`'s instance method `- (NSString *)stringByAppendingPathExtension:(NSString *)ext`. If the file you're looking for is in a bundle you can use `NSBundle`'s instance methods like `- (NSString *)pathForResource:(NSString *)name ofType:(NSString *)extension` or `- (NSString *)pathForResource:(NSString *)name ofType:(NSString *)extension inDirectory:(NSString *)subpath` if the resource is in a folder reference somewhere underneath the top-level bundle directory.

If you want to add more files later without needing to modify your code, you might consider loading the resource names from an array in a property list (`.plist`) resource using `NSDictionary`'s `- (id)initWithContentsOfFile:(NSString *)aPath`.

Comment: In iOS, there's no `Resources` folder. Instead, [the top-level bundle directory is used](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSBundle/pathForResource:ofType:inDirectory:). Otherwise, +1.